# Send messages to Azure Storage Queue in parallel from PowerShel

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

How do you send messages to a queue in parallel?

I tried this:

```
$queue = Get-AzureStorageQueue -Name 'itemsqueue' -Context $context
1..100 | % {
    $msgContent = "This is message $_"

    Start-Job {
        $queue.CloudQueue.AddMessage($msgContent)
    }
}

Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

but $queue is null. I also tried passing it as param($queue), did not work neither.

Any ideas without having to do Get-AzureStorageQueue in each job?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the ```-ArgumentList``` parameter of ```start-job```

Comment: @PeterSchneider, this should not work. Because there is a deserialized process , $queue would be converted to string type. Then it cannot call the AddMessage method.

Comment: @Carlos Garcia, does the answer below work for you?

Comment: Thanks @IvanYang, that explains the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background jobs are built on top of PowerShell remoting and as such, perform similar actions when passing objects around.

They would serialize/ deserialize them rather than pass them with all their complexity, which means that even you use the `-ArgumentList parameter of start-job`, the $queue will deserialize to a string type(or others) which does not have the AddMessage() method.

Here is a workaround using `BeginInvoke`, which does the same thing as the job did:

```
  $context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName your_account -StorageAccountKey your_key
  $queue = Get-AzureStorageQueue -Name 'myqueue0905' -Context $context

  1..10 | % {

  $m1 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage -ArgumentList "this is a message $_"

  $script = {param($p1,$m1) $p1.CloudQueue.AddMessage($m1)}

  $p=[powershell]::Create()

  $n=$p.AddScript($script).addargument($queue).addargument($m1)

  $job=$p.BeginInvoke()
}
```

My test result as below:
[image]

The messages are added in azure portal:
[image]